# Isso é um bug no SWITCH do PHP?

Tags: php, switch

Estou tentando fazer um `switch` no PHP, mas ele me retorna uns valores muito estranhos.

Por exemplo, se a variável `$xp` for igual a `0`, ele me retorna que o nível é `20`.

Não estou entendendo '-'

```
switch($xp){
        case($xp <= 60);
        $nivel = 0;
        break;

        case($xp <= 200);
        $nivel = 1;
        break;

        case($xp <= 350);
        $nivel = 2;
        break;

    //... vários case dps.

        case($xp <= 4375);
        $nivel = 18;
        break;

        case($xp <= 5000);
        $nivel = 19;
        break;

// se $xp for igual a 0 ele me retorna $nivel = 20
        case($xp > 5000);
        $nivel = 20;
        break;
    }
```

O `$xp` é retornado do banco, é um `INT`.

Comment: antes do switch case, se você der um `echo var_dump($xp)` mostra o que?

Comment: string(1) "0" é o q mostra.

Comment: o switch não funciona assim como você imagina, acho que no seu caso um `if(condition) {} elseif(condition) {}` seria melhor mesmo

Comment: No caso do switch, leia assim para melhor entender o funcionamento: "caso x for { igual a 60, então tal } { igual a 80, então tal }{ igual a 200, então tal }"

Comment: Ué mas o switch não veio para substituir um amontoado de if e elses ?

Comment: Ah entendi. O switch seria para comparar um valor exato e nao um range entre valores.

Comment: Até consegue comparar valores, mas não acho que seria a melhor abordagem, você conseguiria fazer assim, por exemplo: caso x for igual a 60, for igual a 61, for igual a 62, .... for igual a 80 { faça isso } for igual a 81, for igual a 82, .... for igual a 100 { faça aquilo }

Comment: Como eu preciso comparar valores altos, vai ser uma eternidade. Bom vou tentar com if, ja que não há mudança na lógica, só na estrutura mesmo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não há nenhum bug no `switch`. O problema está na lógica do seu código. Pois, para todos os cases, está retornando verdadeiro, já que `0` é menor do que qualquer um dos valores dos seus cases, com exceção do `$xp > 5000`. Logo, ele está retornando a atribuição do último case. Se remover o `case($xp > 5000)`, verá que o valor de `$nivel` será 19.

No seu caso, o ideal, por menos intuitivo que pareça, é usar `if` e `else if`, devido ao intervalo que você está utilizando. O `switch` é utilizado em caso de `cases` exatos, como o interruptor de uma lâmpada, o seletor de uma máquina de lavar, etc.

Você até conseguiria se utilizar da estrutura switch, mas seu código provavelmente ficaria muito grande e inviável, seria algo assim:

```
switch($xp){
    case(60): case(61): case(62): case(...): case(199):
        $nivel = 0;
        break;
    case(200): case(201): case(202): case(...): case(499):
        $nivel = x;
        break;
    ....
    default:
        break;
```

Com `else if`:

```
if($xp > 0 && $xp < 200){
    $nivel = 0;
}else if($xp > 200 && $xp < 500){
    $nivel = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já foi explicado o motivo do erro, e que o que você quer não é com `switch`, mas isso não significa que um monte de `if else` seja a melhor opção

Um exemplo com array e um loop:

```
//Crie um array em que as chaves são
//os níveis e os valores serão o que
//irá usar para comparar
$array = [
  0 => [0, 60],
  1 => [60, 200],
  2 => [200, 350]
  //...
];

//Por padrão o nível vai ser 20, seria como um else
$nivel = 20;

//Percorre o array e verifica o valor da
//variável $xp com as chaves
foreach ($array as $chave => $valor) {
  //Se o $xp for > ou = ao primeiro numero do $valor
  //e for menor que o segundo numero do $valor
  if ($xp >= $valor[0] && $xp < $valor[1]) {
    //A variavel $nivel recebe a chave
    $nivel = $chave;
  }
}
```

Assim você terá apenas uma condição (que será executada uma vez para cada item dentro do loop), se precisar adicionar um novo nível ou mudar o antigo, basta atualizar o array

Nesse caso as chaves do `$array` não precisariam ser definidas explicitamente, mas deixei para melhor entendimento